# Change width of browser window after resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change browser width after resize below is my code i tried using resize function for jQuery.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if( $(this).width()<500){
        $(window).width(500);
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't do this. Resizing browser, popup windows, or whatever to 'keep users in check' is, besides usually impossible, regarded as highly irritating. I'd say almost as annoying as flash intro's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Control of the browser window width via javascript is restricted in most modern browsers. Unless the user has specifically allowed it in their settings (which is highly unlikely) you will not be able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to set a min width at your document of 500px, this is the only way you can do that properly

Answer (score 0):

Try to set width of body and html instead.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if( $(this).width()<500){
        $('html,body').css('width', '500px');
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried changing width of body but it just change width of inner content not width of window so user is able to resize window.